# Media Queries for printing not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**HTML**

```
<div id="printDiv" style="display:none">
    <p>some content here</p>
</div>

<input type="button" id="btnPrint" value="Print"/>

<div>
    <img src="http://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/79000/79831/myanmar_tm5_2004349.jpg" height="10000px"/>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $("#btnPrint").click(function(){
        window.print();
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
@media print {
    body * {
       display: none;
    }
    #printDiv, #printDiv * {
       display: block;
    }
    #printDiv {
       position: absolute;
       left: 0;
       top: 0;
    }
}
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/Nu5SX/7/

I want to print a div using Media Queries.
But it is printing white page.
Please help..

Answer (score 2):

Because the css specificity of

```
style="display:none"
```

overrides the CSS rule

Set the display none in the regular CSS file, not in an inline attribute.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@media print {
    body * {
       display: none;
    }
    #printDiv, #printDiv * {
       display: block !important;
    }
    #printDiv {
       position: absolute;
       left: 0;
       top: 0;
    }
}
```